# Data Scraping Futbin player images

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
    for page in range(1, 5):
        req = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players?page='+str(page))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

   numbers = [1,2]
   for number in numbers:
       players = soup.findAll('tr','player_tr_'+str(number))
       for p in players:

       x = p.select('img[src^="https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/"]')
       clubImage = x[0]['src']
       nationalityImage = x[1]['src']
       leagueImage = x[2]['src']
```

Hi,I'm scraping from Futbin.com with this method, I can access the club picture, country picture and league picture of the players. But I can't access the player's own picture. I just want to access the link where the player is. How can I do it? Check image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hc82.png)

Comment: Is the indentation of the code you've posted correct?

Comment: yea, this code is working.

Comment: Are you sure? For example, `req.text` is only going to be `page==4`. And `p.select` will only run for the very last player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for page in range(1, 5):
    req = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players?page='+str(page))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

    players = soup.findAll('img')
    for p in players:

        x = p.get("data-original")
        if x and "players" in x:
            print(f"Name: {p.get('alt')}; Link: {x}")
```

Output

```
Name: Pelé 98; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/237067.png?v=23
Name: Diego Maradona 97; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/190042.png?v=23
Name: Ronaldo 96; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/37576.png?v=23
Name: Zinedine Zidane 96; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/1397.png?v=23
Name: Diego Maradona 95; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/237074.png?v=23
Name: Pelé 95; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/237068.png?v=23
Name: Ferenc Puskás 94; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/254642.png?v=23
Name: Johan Cruyff 94; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/190045.png?v=23
Name: Lev Yashin 94; Link: https://cdn.futbin.com/content/fifa22/img/players/238380.png?v=23
...................
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried but i got this error. `print(f"Name: {p.get('alt')}; Link: {x}")
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @BarCode you use python < 3.7. Change line like this `print("Name: {}; Link: {}".format(p.get('alt'), x))`

Comment: Cool, this is work. One more thing. I want only link data without name.

Comment: @BarCode `x` - is link. `print(..)` you can delete